# Unix command to convert xls file into xlsx file?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix

I there any unix command which will convert xls file into xlsx file?

Also i have tried using mv command, it is changing the extension as well. But then i am not able to open the xlsx file.

```
mv .xls .xlsx
```

Any suggestion will be really appreciate.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Rename the file, convert its format, or what?

Comment: I want to change the extension of xls file to .xlsx??

Comment: Same question on the appropriate SE site with more answers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354043/convert-xlsx-to-xls-in-linux-shell-script

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not something you can easily do with standard unix tools.

You can use LibreOffice:

```
libreoffice --convert-to xlsx my.xls --headless
```

Or maybe find an online converter and submit your file to it.

Comment: I am getting this -bash: libreoffice: command not found
??

Comment: @HussainShabbir You don't have LibreOffice installed. You can try installing it, or look for other ways, of which I am not aware.

Comment: I try to do this, but nothing happens, not even an error message. Any ideas what's the matter? This is using version LibreOffice 4.0.4.2

Comment: @Nick Are you sure the file is not created? (although on my system with 4.3.5.2.0 I see a message when the conversion is finished)

Comment: @LevLevitsky no files are created, and no message. I've tried using the --convert-to csv, xlsx, xlsx:"Calc MS Excel 2007 XML", none of them produce any files.

Comment: @Nick That's strange; (but note that with my version, the file is created in the current working directory and not in the directory of the input file). I can only suggest checking the return code and searching for this problem elsewhere or asking a question on [su].

Comment: @LevLevitsky I followed advice at http://diegolamonica.info/how-to-ake-libreoffice-headless-to-work-on-centos-6-3/ and found that fixed it; I had only installed the libreoffice-headless and required packages, but not the calc package. But it didn't give any error message or return code, which wasn't too helpful! :)