# Possible ways to convert excel file formats from xls to xlsx for use in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, pyexcel

Im using `openpyxl` and have a file with dynamically changing structure.I was supposed to do  a parser, which based on matches of the values of cells with the elements of the list paren `category = [pc1, pc2...]`, gives the coordinates of cells. But the problem is that I can't use the search by parent category name, because these names are not unique and often in the text. 
The next steps I decided to associate the search by style, not by text match. In a file, information about the parent category is contained in the merged cells of a certain color. 
I wrote a parser that finds the cells I need by color and their property - merged cells. 
And this way worked for xlsx format. But I also need to use the old xls format. To convert from `xls` to `xlsx`, I use the `pyexcel` library.

```
 if filename.endswith('.xls'):
    import pyexcel
    _f, _ = filename.split('.')
    pyexcel.save_book_as(file_name=file, dest_file_name=f'{_f}.xlsx')
```

But as it turned out at conversion somehow transfer of style properties is broken and there is no possibility to receive coordinates of a cell by colour or property of merging.

**using merged cell**

```
workbook = load_workbook(filename=file)
sheet = workbook["RFI"]
# get the list of first cell of merged cell coordinate
list_of_first_coordinate_in_merget_cell = [cell.__str__().split(':')[0] for cell in sheet.merged_cell_ranges]
for range_ in sheet.merged_cell_ranges:
    # get current coordinate from all merget cell and set it as a string
    cell_obj_to_str = (range_.__str__())
```

In this case `merged_cell_ranges` doesnt work

**using color**

```
def test_excel_file_response(file):
    pc_coordinate = {}
    workbook = load_workbook(filename=file)
    sheet = workbook["RFI"]
    for row_cells in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=4):
        for cell in row_cells:
            if cell.value in paren_category_ and cell.fill.start_color.rgb:
                pc_coordinate[cell.value] = cell.coordinate
                print(cell.value, cell.fill.start_color)
    return pc_coordinate
```

In this case `cell.fill.start_color` doesnt work

I created issues on github on these subjects. 
https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel/issues/206
https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel/issues/207

All conversion information is based on using the `pyexcel` or `win32com` library for Windows (I'm using Ubuntu). Are there any other conversion methods that work with Ubuntu and Python3.7 and save styles during processing? 
Any advice or recommendation is welcome because I am at a complete standstill...

Comment: For converting you might be better off using OpenOffice in headless mode.

Comment: @CharlieClark Yeah, I tried running a conversion using OpenOffice on a local machine. It works, but the problem is that the production server is AWS. And there is no way to install OpenOffice.

Comment: @CharlieClark Maybe there is experience in how in openpyxl can make a cell unique in one way or another, but not in styles. Some kind of hidden tag or something like that?

Comment: The issue isn't related to openpyxl so I can't really help. Maybe you can post the XLS file to a service that can handle the conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are ok to use other libraries for conversion below lines may help you..

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_excel('excel.xls', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df.to_excel('output.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
```

Comment: pandas does not save styles

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save styles, formulas, dropdowns etc. use libreoffice(soffice) in ubuntu.

```
libreoffice --convert-to xlsx my.xls --headless
```

We can also use subprocess in python to get the desired output as follows:-

```
subprocess.call(['libreoffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'xlsx', 'my.xls'])
```

- The library [xlstoxlsx](https://pypi.org/project/xls2xlsx/) saves the styles, but not the dropdowns, formulas etc.
- We can also do conversion with help of xlrd, but it does not save dropdowns, formulas etc.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21531316/3177661